The intersection of two triangles forms 6 equal circles
This is a problem from the 43rd Russian ITOT competition. I have a problem with the construction of this problem. The problem is as follows: Two intersecting triangles form a hexagon, and from it six small triangles are cut out (see the drawing). Knowing that the radii of the inscribed circles of these six small triangles are equal. Prove that the radii of the inscribed circles of the two original triangles are also equal.
The answer to the problem is at the following link: https://turgor.ru/problems/43/vs-43-sol-fin.pdf

My idea is to construct one triangle first and then draw three equal circles inscribed at the three corners. But to construct the remaining triangle, I don't know what to do next. Can you give me a hint on how to construct the remaining triangle?. Thanks.
EDIT
@Intelligenti_pauca I tried but I don't see the center of the 6 circles located on the Ellipse. When trying with Geogebra, I found that with triangle $ABC$ and three equal circles inscribed in three corners, there exists only a satisfying triangle $DEF$. Is there any relationship to determine the $AM/AB$ ratio?


Experimenting with GeoGebra I found that the centers of the six circles lie on an ellipse.

@Intelligenti_pauca I tried but I don't see the center of the 6 circles lying on the Ellipse. When experimenting with Geogebra, I found that with triangle $ABC$ and three congruent circles inscribed at the three corners, there exists only one satisfactory triangle $DEF$. I'm looking for a connection to construct the 4th circle.

In the second image the ellipse looks quite close to the sixth point. That might be due to some slight inaccuracy in the construction.

I retract my idea that the centers of the six circles lie on an ellipse, see this figure: https://i.sstatic.net/oNHFUiA4.png Instead, it looks like the three main diagonals of the inner hexagon are concurrent.

This is a nice puzzle. While I do not have a construction for you, below is a solution.
We can quickly establish that the large triangles share much in common: the central hexagon, and sectors marked 1-6. Thus, the large triangles only differ in the sectors $XYZ$ and $X'Y'Z'$, respectively. One route that may lead to a solution is to assemble these sectors about a little incircle and embed them in larger triangles, then a dilation brings each into the larger triangles so that the little circle would become the incircle. I did not find a solution in that direction though. However, another route works.

The trick is to do away entirely with XYZ, X'Y'Z'. We have two figures with equal area and equal perimeter, as below, where we only do not know whether the tips beyond the red lines are equal. But we do not need to know this. If we trim each figure by the radius of the little circles, we remove equal rectangles (red radius x 2 x 1-6) from each figure, yielding triangles with equal area and equal (semi)perimeter, therefore, since $A=sr$, their inradii are equal. And dilations about the incenters of $I(\frac{r+red radius}{r})$ brings those equal inradii into equal inradii of the larger triangles.

EDIT: Reversing the above process does not in general yield satisfactory triangles. But I agree with Intelligenti pauca in that satisfactory points lie on an ellipse. The red triangle below is back-constructed as in my answer, the left blue point is not part of fitting the ellipse but sits right on it.

